# highlight menu items based on associated content

Tags: jquery, menu

I am using jQuery to display content on a website based upon the menu item selection.  Each menu item has an number attached to it that matches the content div container.

```
    $(".main-cat").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find("div.arrow-right").remove();
    $(this).after('<div class="arrow-down"></div>');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
},
    function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().find("div.arrow-down").remove();
});

$("#sidebar div").click(function() {
    $("#real_0").hide();
    $(".content_sub").hide();
    var menuClass = $(this).attr('class');
    menuClassP = menuClass.split(" ");
    $("#real_" + menuClassP[1]).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

I am trying to add a function that will highlight only the menu item that corresponds to the **currently** **active** content.

What's the best way to write this? And can my current code be made cleaner?

Comment: You could use the `rel` attribute to hold the class that you need. Rather than splitting the string. It would be a bit more clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
```

in your click handler, and define a `selected` class in your CSS that defines the highlight style..

This will add the class `selected` to the currently clicked element (*assuming that is the **active** content*), and remove it from its siblings (*the other divs in the sidebar*)

Comment: I think this works, but the only conflict is that I also have another function that adds a hover effect which removes the 'selected' applied style on hover out.  I added the code above.

Comment: @MG1, use a different class name.. you can define multiple classes in css with `.selected, .highlight {foo:bar; ...}` and apply the `highlight` for the `click` and the `selected` for the `hover` ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery data attribute by setting something like "data-menuid" for each menu item as an attribute. This way you dont have to split the class name and use it.

```
<li data-menuid="1">menu</li>

$("#sidebar div").click(function() {
    $("#real_0").hide();
    $(".content_sub").hide();
    $("#real_" + $(this).data("menuid")).fadeIn('slow');
});
```